# Is there a body of academic theory (particularly conferences and journals) on role-playing games?

Tags: online-resources

I'm interested in the process of using role-playing table top games to workshop scenes and characters in novels.  I've found it quite hard to find critical materials on role-playing games in general and I'm struggling to believe that there isn't a whole set of academics that spend their lives looking into this.

So - are there any academic conferences slash journals that focus on the social mechanics of role playing game groups?

Comment: Hi Joe, When you say "Social Mechanics" are you referring to game play mechanics? Or theories on how social interaction between the players themselves work? (A quick google returns [this paper](https://digitalcommons.pace.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1199&context=honorscollege_theses) so I'm sure with a little more time you could get plenty back. What is it you're aiming to investigate?

Comment: @LioElbammalf - specificity not the game play mechanics - I'm interested in the social aspects around teamwork and creating a narrative.

Comment: Social mechanics of RPG are the topic of some psychologic journal essays.

Comment: [Google Scholar search for "table top" and "role-playing game"](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&num=100&ie=UTF-8&q=%22table+top%22+%22role-playing+game%22) gives >1,400 results.

Comment: For work from the 90's you might look through [Interactive Fantasy Magazine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Fantasy).  All four issues of its short print run are available at [DriveThruRPG](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/388989/Interactive-Fantasy-issues-14-all-issues).  No affiliation.

Answer (score 18):

#### Begin your research with former site moderator Brian Ballsun-Stanton.

[Brian Ballsun-Stanton](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/760/brian-ballsun-stanton) is a former moderator of this site, and he is an accomplished philosopher and sociologist. His profile links two papers that may be of particular interest to you:

- [Brian Ballsun-stanton, Samuel Russell (2012) Constrained Optimization in Dungeons and Dragons : A Theory of Requirements Generation for Effective Character Creation.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235989095_Constrained_Optimization_in_Dungeons_and_Dragons_A_Theory_of_Requirements_Generation_for_Effective_Character_Creation)
- [Brian Ballsun-stanton, Ernest Mueller, C Ross Eskridge (2012) Clerics , Magic Users , Fighters and Thieves : Theoretical Approaches to Rules Questions on the Role-Playing Games Stack Exchange.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235989093_Clerics_Magic_Users_Fighters_and_Thieves_Theoretical_Approaches_to_Rules_Questions_on_the_Role-Playing_Games_Stack_Exchange)

This first paper references another article that may be of interest:

- [Marcus Mantola (2009) The Invisible Rules of Role-Playing: The Social Framework of Role-Playing Process](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/273946812_The_Invisible_Rules_of_Role-Playing_The_Social_Framework_of_Role-Playing_Process)

The bibliographies of these papers should give you a good place to start your research.

Comment: While bibliographies carry a risk of following an academic echo chamber they are definitely a good place to start, +1

Comment: What ever happened to him? He just sort of vanished after producing some of the best answers on the site.

Comment: @TimothyAWiseman, he failed a will save against geas and had to do a lecture series in the astral plane.

Answer (score 6):

The [International Journal of Roleplaying](https://journals.uu.se/IJRP) sounds like an excellent launching point; a paper on [The Invisible Rules of Role-Playing: The Social Framework of Role-Playing Process](https://journals.uu.se/IJRP/article/view/184) sounds relevant to you.